# Update Classification using Apache ATLAS REST API

Tags: python, rest, curl, apache-atlas

I would like to update tags associated to an entity using apache ATAS REST API.

For example :

Entity with this guid:`81a38d33-a646-4bf6-9310-452947cc5a5a` has three tags associated to it `[main_tag,support_tag,conf_tag]`
I want to have new tags associated to this guid ex: `[new_tag1,new_tag2]` and delete the old ones.

I tried the update using the rest api from apache atlas it doesn't seem to work.

https://atlas.apache.org/api/v2/